# Am I vaccinated?

Tags: code-golf, string

**Disclaimer: the content of this post *is not medical information* and should not be used for any medical purpose, as it is deliberately oversimplified for the purpose of the challenge.**

There are several different strains of [*Neisseria meningitidis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neisseria_meningitidis), the bacterium that causes meningococcal meningitis. Vaccines are available for strains A, B, C, W, and Y. They are available in three combinations.

The first is the quadrivalent meningococcal ACWY vaccine. As the name implies, this protects against strains A, C, W, and Y, but not B.

The second is the meningococcal B vaccine, which protects only against strain B.

The third is the pentavalent meningococcal ABCWY vaccine, which combines ACWY and B to protect against all five strains. Receiving the ABCWY vaccine is equivalent to receiving ACWY and B simultaneously.

However, while only one dose of ACWY is needed for full vaccination (we're ignoring boosters), two doses of B are needed. ABCWY counts as one dose of ACWY and one dose of B.

Write a program or function that accepts either an array of strings, or several strings delimited by a string of your choice. (The empty string is an acceptable delimiter; i.e., you may accept the strings run together.) These strings will be from the set `ACWY`, `B`, and `ABCWY`. Return or print `ACWY` if at least one dose of ACWY has been given but zero or one doses of B have been given, `B` if at least two doses of B but no doses of ACWY have been given, and `ABCWY` if at least one dose of ACWY and at least two doses of B have been given. If neither vaccine has been fully received, output the empty string. "Overvaccination" is allowed; `ABCWY ABCWY ACWY` should become `ABCWY`. You do not have to support invalid inputs.

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `ABCWY B` | `ABCWY` |
| `ABCWY` | `ACWY` |
| `B` | [empty string] |
| `B B` | `B` |
| `ACWY B B` | `ABCWY` |
| `ACWY B` | `ACWY` |

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to schedule my second Men B dose :p

Comment: Can we take a single string with no delimiters?

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms you're welcome! I'm getting mine either this week or next too. That's what inspired the question. :)

Comment: @NickKennedy yes, that is acceptable.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that we don't have to care about "improper" inputs such as `AWY B` (missing C in ACWY)?

Comment: @Stef that is correct.

Comment: You've reminded me that I got my first B dose 5 years ago and never went back for the second... maybe I'll go schedule one too

Comment: I did not expect this site to send me to a Google search for this vaccine in France. Apparently it is not recommended here for adults (it is only in specific situations). It looks like that it elsewhere though - interesting.

Answer (score 7):

## Google Sheets, 64 bytes

```
=join(,ifna(filter({"A","B","CWY"},search({"A","B*B","A"},A1))))
```

Put the input in cell `A1` and the formula in cell `B1`.

Uses the `search()` with `*` wildcard method of [JvdV's Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268657/119296).

The same can be done without arrays using simple string concatenation and regexes (**81 bytes**):

```
=let(a,regexmatch(A1,"A"),if(a,"A",)&if(regexmatch(A1,"B.*B"),"B",)&if(a,"CWY",)
```

Implementation of the same in JavaScript (**62 bytes**):

```
t=>(a=/A/.test(t)?'A':'')+(/B.*B/.test(t)?'B':'')+(a?'CWY':'')
```

<sup>(-4 bytes thanks to [noodle man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/noodle-man))</sup>

Comment: the JS can be 62 bytes `t=>(a=/A/.test(t)?'A':_='')+(/B.*B/.test(t)?'B':_)+(a?'CWY':_)`

Comment: @noodleman thanks.

Comment: Port of my Excel answer for 70 bytes: `=INDEX(JOIN(,REPT({"A","B","CWY"},COUNTIF(A1,{"*A*","*B*B*","*A*"}))))`. This can probably be shortened a bit?

Comment: @JvdV thanks. Your `mid()` works out shorter still.

Comment: `=JOIN(,IFNA(FILTER({"A";"B";"CWY"},SEARCH({"A";"B*B";"A"},A1))))` for 64 bytes. Thanks to another user on LinkedIn =)

Comment: @JvdV thanks. The arrays can be horizontal which is easier on the eye.

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```perl
$_=A x/A/.B x/B.*B/.CWY x/A/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZRoULfUV/PCUg56Wk56es5h0eChf7/d3QCsZ24wDSXE5cTiA0WgjP@5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0@K9bkAMA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
œ-”BQṢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oZN1HDXOdAh/uXPT/4e4th9sfNa2J/P/f0ck5PNKJC0xxOXE5AZkgASgFAA)

A monadic link taking a string with no delimiter and returning a string.

### Explanation

```
œ-”B   | Set difference with "B"
    Q  | Uniquify
     Ṣ | Sort
```

Comment: I see that you beat me to thinking of using the multiset difference atom, I have noted that in mine now linking here :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks! Our original posts were only three minutes apart I think

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda s:"A"*(x:="C"in s)+"B"*(s.count("B")>1)+"CWY"*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfpmAb8z8nMTcpJVGh2ErJUUlLo8LKVslZKTNPoVhTW8kJKFCsl5xfmleiAeRo2hkCBZ3DI5W0Kv4XFGUCRdM0lBydgCIKQFlNLlQxFBFUeSd09WAjsAoChf4DAA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
def f(s):x="C"in s;return"A"*x+"B"*(s.count("B")>1)+"CWY"*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo1jTqsJWyVkpM0@h2LootaS0KE/JUUmrQlvJSUlLo1gvOb80r0QDyNG0M9TUVnIOjwRK/i8oygSKpmkoOToBRRSAsppcqGIoIqjyTujqwUZgFQQK/QcA)

Comment: Why specify "pre-release" for the 3.8 version? 3.8 has been out for years. Also, just writing out `("C"in s)` longhand and using otherwise the same `lambda` works in older Python 3 (and at least 2.7, probably much earlier) and is also 59 bytes.

Comment: The walrus operator in 3.8+ makes it a little shorter, but not backwards compatible, plus the formatting is just copied from TIO which specifies 3.8 as a pre-release. And yeah the lambda written out is the same length, but I like that it's the concept in both of my entries... I'm sure someone on here can do better tho

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 / 48 / 41 bytes

Expects a space-separated string.

```javascript
s=>[...new Set(s.replace("B",""))].sort().join``.trim()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7BCoJAEMbxe08xzGkXanwCg7ZH6BAhgmKjKLq77C5FT7@ZWQRKx2F@8P278lb6yrU27LS5cqzT6NN9RkSa73DiIDw5tn1ZsUCFW0Qpc/LGBSGpM60uCgquHYSMldHe9Ey9aUQt8KCO5wsoBCkhSWA6N2sGAT5mhajXG74k48GGB/hxUzf5AsPM31gt9qakEf1rmrN/muIT)

Or **[48 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc5BCsIwEIXhvacIs0pApyeoYDyCiyKl0FKnpSVmQhIUTx9t60JocXYDH7x/bB5NaP3g4sHyjVKXp5AfS0S09BQXijKgJ2ealiRo2AMoVWFgH6XCkQdb16llG9gQGu5lJ@Gkz8VVf5zIMjE/uy0B4is2gAYx3QJKurv4EiH6wfbVii52oXq1NKX8b5ljf1rSGw)** if we take a string with no delimiter.

Or **[41 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc5BCsIwEIXhvacIs0pApyeoYDyCC5HSRYjTUqlJyATF00fbuBBanN3AB@@/mYdhG4eQds5fKXd15nrfIKKjpzhRkoyRwmgsSdCwBVCqRfYxSZWtd@xHwtH3spNw0MfzRX@AqCoxP5s1AeIrVoAGMV0BDd1DeglOcXB9u6DFFqoXS1PK/5Y59qclvwE)** if we return an array.

### Method

Given the input string, e.g. `"ABCWY ACWY B"`:

- remove the first "B" → `"ACWY ACWY B"`
- turn the string into a set → `Set { 'A','C','W','Y',' ','B' }`
- turn the set into an array → `[ 'A','C','W','Y',' ','B' ]`
- sort it in lexicographical order → `[ ' ','A','B','C','W','Y' ]`
- turn it back into a string → `" ABCWY"`
- remove the leading space, if any → `"ABCWY"`

Comment: You can save 7 bytes, if you take the input [delimited by the empty string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268620/am-i-vaccinated?newreg=48e3fc6d352d475f8f70fcbf0b2a8fe1#comment583696_268620) and remove the `.trim()`

Comment: @JeanotZubler Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't notice the empty delimiter was allowed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 6 bytes

```
"B"∕uo
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FiuUnJQedUwtzV9SnJRcDBVccFNLydHJOTzSSYkLwgDSILYTWAAkAWcoQbQAAA)

A port of [@Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268624/9288).

```
"B"∕uo
"B"∕    Set difference with "B"
    u   Uniquify
     o  Sort
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 16 bytes

```
\W

1`B

O`.
D`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyaci8swwYmLyz9Bj8slQe//f0cn5/BIBScuMM3lxOUEYoOF4AwA) Link includes test cases. Accepts any non-`\w` characters as a delimiter. Explanation:

```
\W
```

Join the words together.

```
1`B
```

Delete the first `B`, if any.

```
O`.
```

Sort the letters.

```
D`.
```

Deduplicate the letters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), 37 bytes

```bash
sed s/B//|grep -o .|sort -u|tr -d \\n
```

#### Explanation

```
sed s/B// | # remove the first occurrence of B
grep -o . | # insert a newline after every character
sort -u   | # sort lines and remove duplicates
tr -d \\n | # remove newlines inserted for sorting
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Note while I did eventually think of using `œ-` to avoid a byte, I now see that [Nick Kennedy actually got there first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268624/53748)!

```
Fœ-”BQṢ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters (the vaccines) and yields a list of characters (the fully vaccinated).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t6GTdRw1znQIf7lz0////aCVH5/BIJR0FJSelWAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t6GTdRw1znQIf7lz0/@HuLYe26jzcselwu0qWw6OmNY8a9ykpabr//@/o5BweqeDEBaa5nLicQGywEJwBkVOAkiBljjAWAA).

#### How?

```
Fœ-”BQṢ - Link: list of strings (from "B", "ACWY", "ABCWY"), Vaccinations
F       - flatten
 œ-”B   - multiset difference with 'B'
     Q  - deduplicate
      Ṣ - sort
```

---

Alternative [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oZN1HDXOdDs9wTPv/cPeWQ1t1DrdnOTxqWvOocZ@Skqb7//@OTs7hkQpOXGCay4nLCcQGC8EZEDkFKAlS5ghjAQA):

Taking a non `[A-Z]` separating string (like `" "` or `", "`, etc):

```
œ-”BØAf
œ-”B     - multiset difference with 'B'
    ØAf  - "ABC...XYZ" filter keep
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.sort().filter(x=>!~(s[x]=~-s[x]),s.B=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9BCsIwEADvvmLNKQG7xQekYHyESMih1LRUalOyQeqlX49Ei3po8bQszLCz1/JeUuXbIWS9u9hYy0iyICTnAxdYt12wno@y2E6c9GjklKUhdoRK7kWsXE@us9i5htdcIyI7qOPprBgYISDP4bVu1jgG8AFXOJUY@HLa3obwAAq@7RuzaMzKLKjF6ylSsb@R719@G@MT)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...'ABCWY'].filter(x=>s.split(x)[x=='B'?2:1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5BC8IgFMDxe5/i4UU95Khj4CL7EBGyw1huGKZDJezTWzgWwUbHx/s93v/ePtvQeT3GrXU3lXueA68lYwyfxPlyxQ3rtYnKk8TrwMJodCSJysQ5Fvi4P@wamjtngzOKGTeQnqByCAIQUApVBWXerCIEMKMVI8oevkaqxxhfEKLXdmiWevaTFouXU9ZH/eua23@68hs)

+4 bytes if a trailing delimited is not allowed.

Worse than Arnauld's solution (41, if it use no delimit and output array)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'Bõ.;ê
```

Port of [*@NickKennedy*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268624/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3enwVj3rw6v@/3d0Do90cgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf3Wnw1v1rA@v@q/z39HJOTzSiQtMcTlxOQGZIAEoBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
   .;   # In the (implicit) input-string, replace the first
'B     '# "B"
  õ     # with an empty string ""
     ê  # Then sort and uniquify the characters of the string
        # (which is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel ms365, <sup><s>64</s></sup>63 bytes

New:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH({"A","B*B","C"},A1),{1,1,3}),""))
```

Old:

```
=CONCAT(REPT({"A","B","CWY"},COUNTIF(A1,{"*A*","*B*B*","*A*"})))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 50 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join(sorted(set(s.replace('B','',1))))
```

Another port of [@NickKennedy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268624/52210), approximately. Python doesn't have a built-in multiset or corresponding set-difference operator; it does have `collections.Counter`, but that takes way too much setup. Instead, I just remove up to one `B` from the input before uniquifying and sorting (and producing a string from the resulting list). This works in both Python 2 and Python 3. The `count` argument for the `replace` method of strings is not commonly discussed, but it's clearly documented.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.sub(?B,'').chars|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivuDRJw95JR11dUy85I7GouCY6tvZ/gUJatJKjk3N4pIKTkl46SI2SgpKOkpJmLKeyAidYhguhCJsSuApsBkSn5haUVCoUlxRl5qXHQtVhtcoJag3YKQQdg9PBQIn/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>17</s></sup>15 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⎕A∩⊢(/⍨)≠⍲'B'=⊢
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9Q31fFRx8pHXYs09B/1rtB81LngUe8mdSd1W6AQAA&f=K0ktLil@1DZB3dHJOTxSwUldAcJSV9B41LtGR91JXVNB3QkiDlaAxFTnKgHp1ok21DONTTu0AswDAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A tacit function which takes a string on the right using no delimiter or any delimiter that is not a capital letter.
The test cases use spaces.
(The test case `B` is written as `(⍬,'B')` because single characters in quotes are not treated as strings in APL)

```apl
⎕A∩⊢(/⍨)≠⍲'B'=⊢­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
          'B'=⊢  # ‎⁡Boolean mask for all Bs
         ⍲       # ‎⁢NAND
        ≠        # ‎⁣Boolean mask for all first instances
   ⊢(/⍨)         # ‎⁤apply Boolean mask (removes first B)
  ∩              # ‎⁢⁡intersection
⎕A               # ‎⁢⁢capital letter alphabet
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Taking the intersection with the alphabet helpfully removes any delimiters and sorts alphabetically.

This solution doesn't work on any of the APL versions on TIO, as @att describes.

Comment: `≠` as unique mask was added in 18.0, which postdates the 17.1 on tio

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Φα›№θι⁼κ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMtM6cktUgjUUfBvSg1EcR0zi8FihfqKGRq6ii4FpYm5hRrZOsoGGoCgfX//45OzuGR/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Accepts any character that's not an uppercase letter as a delimiter (some characters may need extra quoting). Explanation:

```
 α          Predefined variable uppercase alphabet
Φ           Filtered where
   №        Count of
     ι      Current letter
    θ       In input string
  ›         Is greater than
       κ    Current index
      ⁼     Equals
        ¹   Literal integer `1`
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua 0.8.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 13 bytes <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/SBCSUiua)</sup>

```
⊏⍏.⊝▽≠⇡⧻,⊗@B.
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAg4oqP4o2PLuKKneKWveKJoOKHoeKnuyziipdAQi4KZiJCIgpmIkJCIgpmIkJCQiIKZiJBQ1dZIgpmIkFDV1lCIgpmIkFDV1lCQiIKZiJBQkNXWSIKZiJBQkNXWUIiCmYiQUNXWUFDV1kiCg==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 115 bytes

A Port of [@spooky_simon's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268625/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY6xTsMwEIb3PMXpltqgIioWlMpIcWcmhBCqKmSCHQWZM7JdCKr6GEwsXWDhifo2XJqOEV7u7O-7__z1k2rjzcXvEqcU3k0kXO3n4fHZ1hmuTUuwKQCerIMXvggTm1RCFaP5WN7k2FKzkiXcUptBscnq9zq76eU-9SON6EodgreGpGqd6OQMrE8WzoseO5HKIUSqzZvx0Kl0VgfKvCkJXKCcY4UnnCJPUfdNj9eUxYNSEz2RVzMGi7v7wdkeV38Cn1eOzZ6EE1hpVkCjlMUYGXkfc_V4wiH6HzSAbXH83G431D8)

```scala
def g(x:Boolean)=if(x)1 else 0
def f(s:String)={val x=s.contains("C");"A"*g(x)+"B"*g(s.count(_=='B')>1)+"CWY"*g(x)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZHBasJAEIbxmqf42Ut2Ky2VXkSIkM25p1KKiMiaZjWSbkp2LYjkSbx40buv49O4zSZBSuxtdv5vv2GY_UnHIhMvh8NxY-Tj8NI754t1Ehu8ilRh5wGficSXfVBRLPUIYVGI7fTNFKlaztgI7yo1CCrSsZJayuWsKVoA-BEZVkJHtqWf4lwZq9aURITdAIso3yhTI7aicwQBfO4zjDHwapKSkOABNJWgv0qGAZJMJ3hmDP0W4i3ktHew6GNy11ZBpZv7bRcymaLSjuf2Ezipgb9JR7-L5d2GSv1P5ILSK93l6gM2h7wC)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def f(s: String): String = {
      val hasC = s.contains("C")
      val bCount = s.count(_ == 'B') > 1

      ("A" * (if (hasC) 1 else 0)) +
      ("B" * (if (bCount) 1 else 0)) +
      ("CWY" * (if (hasC) 1 else 0))
    }

    println(f("ABCWY B"))
    println(f("ABCWY"))
    println(f("B"))
    println(f("B B"))
    println(f("ACWY B B"))
    println(f("ACWY B"))
  }
}
```